# PHP SQL Update Database

Tags: php, html, sql

I want, if the user ist already logged in, to update "lastlogin" in the Database. But if I log in nothing happens. No error. "Lastlogin" in the Database stays empty.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '............');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '............');
define('DB_NAME', '............');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


    if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp); 

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin='".$date."' WHERE id=1";

    }

    mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: `erfolg`? Are you sure?

Comment: You're not running any SQL....

Comment: where is `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: I edited it now

Comment: You have built your variable `$sql`, but haven't executed it.

Comment: edited but still no mysqli_query in your code, miss this line `mysqli_query($link, $sql);`

Comment: and how to execute it?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections.

Comment: No it isn't subject to SQL injection, although I guess that is by pure luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget one line?

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp); 

$sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin='".$date."' WHERE id=1";
$response = mysqli_query($link, $sql); //<================== THIS ONE

}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Works, but the date is 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: What is the value of `$timestamp` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually executing your query. Add `mysqli_query()`.

```
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Your current code is open to SQL injections, you should use prepared statements and `bind_param()`:

```
// Assuming you're storing the ID in a session variable
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if(!$link) {die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());}

if($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    // use prepared statements to prevent sql injection
    $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE users SET lastlogin = ? WHERE id = ?');

    // prepare statement
    if(!$stmt) {die('ERROR: Could not prepare statement: ' . $stmt->error);}

    // bind parameters
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('si', $date, $id)) {die('ERROR: Could not bind parameters: ' . $stmt->error);}

    // execute statement  
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {die('ERROR: Could not execute statement: ' . $stmt->error);}
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote this, because `bind_param` fails to bind to the second question mark for the id.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to execute the query!
Try this... should work just fine.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '............');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '............');
define('DB_NAME', '............');

if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
    $link = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Check connection
    if($link->connect_error){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $link->connect_error);
    }
    // Get current date and time
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $id = $_SESSION["id"]; // OR $_POST... $_GET.... WHATEVER
    // Prepare query
    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = ? WHERE id= ?");
    // Bind non safe variables
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $date, $id);
    // Execute and check if successfully updated or return error
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
    } else {
        echo "Last login updated successfully";
    }
    // Close connection
    $link->close();
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote this, because I don't know where `$id` is coming from, and you don't make sure `$id` is an integer (think SQL injection)